# HP 250 laptop doesn't recognize Bluetooth

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

I have a problem with any Ubuntu version on my HP 250 laptop which doesn't recognize Bluetooth. It says `No Bluetooth adapter found`. It has never worked, but now I use this laptop as a work tool, so its resolution is important. I have tried some solutions that I have found by googling, but Ubuntu still does not recognize the Bluetooth device on this laptop. I have also tried with an external Bluetooth connected via USB, but it doesn't recognize it either.

hp@hp-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:9320 Suyin Corp. HP Webcam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `lsusb` with the USB Bluetooth device plugged in? This will show some details about the hardware. This may help someone provide some solutions 

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output Matigo asked for and also i) the version of Ubuntu you are using and ii) the output of `sudo hwinfo | perl -00ne 'print if /Bluetooth Device/'` (this will take a while to run).

Answer (score 0):

hp@hp-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo hwinfo | perl -00ne 'print if /Bluetooth Device/'
sudo: hwinfo: orden no encontrada

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This does not seem to answer the question. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1321273/edit) your question instead, and delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

hp@hp-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:9320 Suyin Corp. HP Webcam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub